# Image in Button: Strange space

Tags: html, button, image, space

First the result in Firefox 4 Beta 8:

[Button vs Div http://b.imagehost.org/0419/buttonSpace.png](http://b.imagehost.org/0419/buttonSpace.png)

The former element shown is a `button` with an `img` the latter is a `div` with an `img`. As you can see in the former case there is some strange space between the border of the `img` and the border of the `button`. I wonder how I can remove it.

Here the CSS file:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

button, img, div {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

img {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the HTML also, if possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Testing the above testcase in other browsers has shown that this probably isn't a CSS issue but a bug in Firefox. After a little bit of research I found this bug report: [Bug 140563 - `<button>` ignores CSS style `padding:0`](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=140562)

In that bug report there is a fix for the problem:

```
button::-moz-focus-inner {padding:0; border:0}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to set a `width` for the `div`

Comment: My question is referring to the strange space in the **former** case. The latter is perfectly clear ;)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `padding` you're asking for is not being applied. Have you tried setting it explicitly on the button?

Comment: I gave the button a `padding: 0 !important`, it still didn't work.