# Image in Button: Strange space 2.0 (this time IE7)

Tags: html, button, internet-explorer-7, image, space

This is a followup to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912731/image-in-button-strange-space). It dealt with a rendering issue in Firefox. After that issue was fixed I obviously tested the design in other browsers. And obviously - how could it be different - I encountered yet another rendering issue, this time in IE7.

[Image in Button rendering issue in Internet Explorer 7 http://b.imagehost.org/0451/NastySpace2.png](http://b.imagehost.org/0451/NastySpace2.png)

The former of the above elements is a `button` containing an `img`. The latter is a `div` containing an `img`.

In the former case (the one with `button` and `img`) there is a space between the border of the `img` and the border of the `button`. I want to get rid of it.

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

button, img, div {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

img {
    display: block;
}

/* this is a fix for one of the padding issues in IE7 */
button {
    overflow: visible;
}
/* this is a fix for the problem in Firefox linked above */
button::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Please help me, I'm starting to feel really pissed to be honest. This is the third `padding` bug I encounter with this `button` tag...

**Edit**: I am giving bounty on this question, to either get a more at-the-root fix for the IE7 problem or for tipoffs about other browser-bugs related to `<button>`s. I want to have a button that looks perfectly, pixel for pixel the same in all major browsers. (PS: IE6 is *not* a major browser.)

Comment: @jball: The css above is the whole CSS. So apart from resetting margin and padding I'm not using a reset stylesheet ;)

Comment: I think you might save yourself a lot of headaches with [a good reset](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/).

Comment: @jball: And I think that the yui reset doesn't apply any styles to `button`...

Comment: It does however alter `img` and `div` styles. I'm not saying it'll fix your problem (hence I'm making a comment and not attempting an answer (also can't see the image you provided)), just saying that I think a reset helps alot with these kinds of cross browser styling issues.

Comment: @jball: At least in this case it is pointless to include the yui reset. Furthermore I think that only the first two rules in the yui reset are of any interest for myself or any other reasonable page and thus I prefer including those manually.

Comment: @jball: I appreciate thoughts. Sorry if I became aggressive.

Comment: I've had the same problem with IE with buttons. You can try using a `<input type='submit'>` and give it the image as a BG (a sprite).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it seems that I must conclude that there is no fix for this one - at least no known fix. Thus I saw no alternative then manually removing this space (using negative margins).

Here is my complete list of fixes that makes the `button` element look the same in Firefox, Safari, Chrome, Opera, Internet Explorer (IE9, IE8, IE7, haven't tested IE6):

```
button img {
    display: block; /* required to get rid of bottom space in many browsers */
    *margin: -1px -1px -3px -1px; /* remove additional space in IE7 */
}

button {
    overflow: visible; /* remove content-size dependent padding in IE7 */
}
button::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: 0;  /* remove inner focus from Firefox. The inner focus takes up */
    padding: 0; /* padding in Firefox even if not focused due to a bug */
}
button:focus {
    outline: 1px dotted black; /* as we removed the inner focus give it an outer focus ring to improve accessibility */
}
```

Compressed version:

```
button img{display:block;*margin:-1px -1px -3px -1px}
button{overflow:visible}
button::-moz-focus-inner{border:0;padding:0}
button:focus{outline:1px dotted black}
```

Removed line breaks:

```
button img{display:block;*margin:-1px -1px -3px -1px}button{overflow:visible}button::-moz-focus-inner{border:0;padding:0}button:focus{outline:1px dotted black}
```

Have fun with consistent `button`s!

Comment: Have you tried using `input type=submit` and applying a bg image to it, or `input type=image`?

Comment: Applying a css bg image for button is even hackier. Thus I prefer this method. Furthermore this provides more styling possibilities (you could put something else than an image in the button)

Comment: But I'll try `input type=image`. If it works that would be okay in this case, too.

Comment: @meder: I am looking for a general solution. `<button>`s may contain more than images. Often you want to have an image and a text. See edit in the question :)

Answer (score 0):

So `display:block` doesn't fix it? How about `vertical-align:bottom` for the img? Can you setup a testcase on jsfiddle.net?

EDIT: `display:block` on the button seems to do it: http://work.arounds.org/sandbox/48/run

**Edit #2**: Stubborn huh.. does this work? http://work.arounds.org/sandbox/48

Comment: Neither solves the problem. `display:block` on `button` actually brings back the problem solved by `overflow:visible`. `vertical-align:bottom` doesn't result in any change. @jsfiddle: I don't really get what this is and how it helps me solve my problem. Looks like some JS thingy.

Comment: It allows you to duplicate the problem so that others can work on it and try to fix it. Or you can use my own personal sandbox, http://work.arounds.org/sandbox/new

Comment: I have given you the bounty, because you a) helped most and b) proposed using `type=image`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding width:auto to the button?

```
button {    
    overflow: visible;
    width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I often find myself cursing at buttons and then solving the problem by displaying an image with an onclick Javascript submit.

Hackish?  Perhaps.  But it's an acceptable solution for the 100+ major credit card websites I did for an international bank....and to date, I haven't found a more picky client.

Comment: I don't like this idea because it requires JavaScript to be enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I get around this issue by using an `<input type="image" />` instead of a `<button />` and using javascript to modify the image shown when the mousedown and mouseup events is triggered.

Try it, it'll save you a big headache.